# When displaying a PowerBuilder datawindow, is it possible to only show a column details when it changes?

Tags: grid, powerbuilder, datawindow

I am displaying a datawindow in PowerBuilder (v12) but for one of the columns only wish to display information in the column if the data has changed, otherwise the user will be subjected to a lot of repeats on the screen.

Is this possible please or must it be done in the SQL I am obtaining the data from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean when it has changed from row to row, going down the list, then this sounds like the feature found in the DataWindow painter under Rows \ Suppress Repeating Values....

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Perfect, Terry! I didn't actually know about that one concealed at the top of the screen... :o\